# How to create Django model for data with multiple images

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I basically want to create a multivalued attribute called images. I created a model called CseDepartment with attributes: title, description, updated and created. Then i created another model called NewsImage with attributes: cseDepartment (foreign key), images, created and updated. But while running the code i get error saying CseDepartment has no attribut called newsImage_set. how to fix this issue?

each news or data in CseDepartment can have multiple images how can i make this work?

[Error shown when accessing template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DewWM.png)

This is what I tried:

views.py:

```
def cse_dept(request):
  dept = CseDepartment.objects.all()
  context = { 'dept' : dept}
  return render(request, 'website/cse_dept.html', context)

def cse_news(request, pk):
  cseDepartment = CseDepartment.objects.get(id=pk)
  images = cseDepartment.newsImage_set.all().order_by('-created')
  context = {'news' : cseDepartment, 'newsImages' : images}
  return render(request, 'website/cse_news.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class CseDepartment(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  image = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  description = models.TextField()
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
  
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
  
class NewsImage(models.Model):
    cseDepartment = models.ForeignKey(CseDepartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.image[0:50]
```

urls.py

```
path('cse_dept/', views.cse_dept, name="d-cse"),
path('cse_news/<str:pk>/', views.cse_news, name="news"),
```

template

```
<h3>{{news.title}}</h3>
        {% for pic in newsImages %}
        <img src="{{pic.image}}" alt="">
        {% endfor %}
```

I want this template to display all the images relating to the selected news of cse department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding a `related_name` to the `NewsImage` model:

```
class NewsImage(models.Model):
    cseDepartment = models.ForeignKey(
        CseDepartment,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="images"
    )
```

That way, you can get your images like:

```
images = cseDepartment.images.all().order_by('-created')
```